# Difference of 2 columns in pandas dataframe with some given conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

[image]

I have a sheet like this. I need to calculate absolute of "CURRENT HIGH" - "PREVIOUS DAY CLOSE PRICE" of particular "INSTRUMENT" and "SYMBOL".
So I used .shift(1) function of pandas dataframe to create a lagged close column and then I am subtracting current HIGH and lagged close column but that also subtracts between 2 different "INSTRUMENTS" and "SYMBOL". But if a new SYMBOL or INSTRUMENTS appears I want First row to be NULL instead of subtracting current HIGH and lagged close column.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need if all days are consecutive per groups:

```
df['new'] = df['HIGH'].sub(df.groupby(['INSTRUMENT','SYMBOL'])['CLOSE'].shift())
```